# Access controls of parent dialog in VB6

Tags: vb6, controls, parent-child

I have a dialog in vb6 which changes the values being displayed in its parent dialog.

The x1 is displayed in txt_c1 text in parent dialog and it has a txt_1validate function too for the text box. Now i want to change the value of txt_c1 txtbox from child dialog and then call its validate function. But the problem is that txt_c1 is not available in child dialog.

Please note that i am working in vb6  in the MS VB 6.0 IDE

Comment: Please can you post some code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: main.frm is my main dialog it contains a text box txc1 and a button on main form opens Form1.frm . now when user presses a button on Form1 the value of txc1 textbox should change and its validate method should be called but the txc1 is not avaiable in from1.frm

Comment: Okay - but I think we need to see the actual code.  For example, the chunk of code that invokes the child form and the validate event.  Without seeing how you are invoking the form, it's not easy to see why you can't access the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are just classes and can therefore be instantiated explictly (and you will probably find your life easier if you do rather than using the automatic instantiation in VB6) and references to forms can be assigned.

You can solve your problem by creating a public property on your child dialog (Form1.frm) of type Form that you set to the instance of the parent dialog thus giving you access to the controls andd methods on the parent from the child.

My VB6 is somewhat rusty (and I don't have an installed instance available) so this isn't going to be actual, correct code - but something along the lines of the following should work

In the code that calls the child:

```
Form childDialog = new Form1
childDialog.Parent = this
childDialog.ShowModal
```

Then in the child dialog:

```
Parent.txt_c1 = newValue
if not Parent.Validate then
...
end if
```

Comment: Not a bad try at VB6, I'm guessing you've moved to C#? I think you mean something like `Dim childDialog As Form1: Set childDialog = New Form1: Set childDialog.Parent = Me: childDialog.Parent.Show vbModal` and then `Parent.txt_c1.Text = newValue: If Not Parent.Validate Then` I would also guess that jaminator may need to make `txt_1validate` Public

Comment: Murph thanks for your answer, my chilad dialogs name is attachmentsFrm and when i try to do Form instance = New attachmentsFrm it is giving error

Comment: @MarkJ yup - probably 8 years now since I did VB.OLD in any meaningful sense.